# How to solve a proof with inequalities and substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation

I've been working through Daniel Solow's [*How to Read and Do Proofs*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/How+to+Read+and+Do+Proofs:+An+Introduction+to+Mathematical+Thought+Processes,+6th+Edition-p-9781118164020) and, for some reason, have difficulty when "combining" inequalities (or substituting variables which involve inequalities, sometimes of different directions and strict vs. non-strict). I am self-studying and haven't taken math courses in over 20 years.

In particular, one example the author provides is a proof of the existence of the non-rational number $\sqrt{2}$. The Proposition and proof are shown in the following screenshot:
[image: this screenshot]

So the author constructs an $x$ that is the infimum of the set $T = \{s \in \mathbb{R} | s \gt 0 \text{ and } s^2 \gt 2 \}$. My struggle is with **S4**; the author provides interpretations for each statement. Here is a screenshot for **S4** (the author uses **A** for the "givens" and **B** for the "goals"):[image: S4]

I understand the author's use of the contradiction method; what I can't figure out is what he states towards the end of the screenshot; i.e., that $s = x - \frac{1}{n} \in T$ (which he writes is not so easy to show). Considering the definition of $T$, it seems to me that this would amount to showing both $x - \frac{1}{n} > 0$ and $\left (x - \frac{1}{n} \right )^2 > 2$. Working from the inequality given, I *think*:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} & \lt \frac{x^2 - 2}{2x} \\
-\frac{1}{n} & \gt \frac{2 - x^2}{2x} \tag{multiply by -1} \\
x - \frac{1}{n} & \gt x + \frac{2 - x^2}{2x} \tag{add x to both sides} \\
x - \frac{1}{n} & \gt \frac{x^2 + 2}{2x} \tag{algebra}
\end{align}

This is where I get stuck. Clearly the numerator of the RHS is positive, and if we were given $x \gt 0$ then the first condition of inclusion in $T$ would follow. But I'm stumped; since the author assumes for **S4** that $x^2 > 2$, can this somehow be used? That is, since $\frac{1}{n}$ is positive and the RHS of the numerator of the first equation is also positive, then $2x \gt 0$ *must* be true?

Finally, how could I prove the 2nd condition; i.e., that $\left (x - \frac{1}{n} \right )^2 > 2$? And beyond my specific question, any tips for getting better at working with these types of problems?

Comment: I did not understand your question well

Comment: I was having trouble showing that $(x - \frac{1}{n})^2 > 2$, using the information given in the final sentence of the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this from S1

$$\forall s \in T :  s^2 > 2 $$

We Know That : $$(x - \frac{1}{n}) \in T $$

Then :

$$(x-\frac{1}{n})^2 > 2 $$